# Tell if UITableView has scrolled to top

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I tried this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScrollToTop:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

But it didn't fire when I scrolled the table view to the top.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

Does fire so the delegate isn't the problem.

In viewDidLoad I also set `[myTbl setDoesScrollToTop:YES];`

Comment: does scrollViewDidScrollToTop fire, when you touch the status bar?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The `scrollViewDidScrollToTop:` method fires when the user clicks on the status bar and the `scrollsToTop` property is set to `YES`. From the docs:

> The scroll view sends this message when it finishes scrolling to the top of the content. It might call it immediately if the top of the content is already shown. For the scroll-to-top gesture (a tap on the status bar) to be effective, the scrollsToTop property of the UIScrollView must be set to YES.

It does not fire if the user manually scrolls to the top. If you want to handle this case you will have to implement the `scrollViewDidScroll:` method and check to see whether the scroll is at the top yourself.

You can check this through the [contentOffset](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentOffset) property e.g.:

```
if (scrollView.contentOffset.y == 0) { // TOP }
```

Comment: Nice, explains a lot.

Comment: I'd like to add that "top" being 0 is not necessarily always true depending on the content insets of the tableview and the surrounding context in general, so you might want to take that into consideration.

Comment: @joakim In my case I did use `scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 0` as condition in `scrollViewDidScroll ` method

Answer (score 6):

When the table view goes under navigation bar and safe area layout guides are enabled, the following check can be done:

```
if (tableView.contentOffset.y + tableView.safeAreaInsets.top) == 0 { ... }
```

Bonus: Check for contentSize if you want to avoid getting 0 before the content is load:

```
if tableView.contentSize.height > 0 && 
    ((tableView.contentOffset.y + tableView.safeAreaInsets.top) == 0) { ... }
```